# Obtaining min and max of partitioned data with a filter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, window-functions

I've just find this problem in a query: (Sorry, I'll try to simplify the table definitions and shorten the details. If you need some more, please, tell me).

I've a table with `(ID, date, status)`. `ID` is a FK, `date` is a date, and `status` is an int value between `1` and `5`. Both `date` and `status` allow null values. Repeated values are also allowed.

What I need:
Extract one row for each `ID`, `min(date)` having an status of `1` or `2`, `min(date)` having an `status` of `2` (only), `max(status)`...

I'm completely lost... I'm trying to use

```
SELECT
   ID,
   min(date) over (partition by(status)) ?? as min_12_date,
   min(date) over (partition by(status)) ?? as min_2_date,
   max(status) as max_status
FROM table
group by ID
```

So, the question is: Is this correct? How can I select only the `status` I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't need analytic functions for this. You only need conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       min(case when status in (1, 2) then date end) as min_12_date,
       min(case when status = 2 then date end) as min_2_date,
       max(status) as max_status
  from tbl
 group by id
```